# How to make WPF Lines a better quality drawing?

Tags: c#, wpf, line

The following picture show that my WPF lines are not as exact like a similar drawing in a non WPF application. So? Where is the problem? antialiasing? or is this a WPF feature? What am I supposed to do?

the below barchart is a simple Shape.Line.

[image]

Comment: Try setting `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` and `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` on container element and see if that helps.

Comment: Check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I would say "better line quality". Subpixel rendering is a feature in many many cases - actually in most. Financial charts are a special case - but saying WPF lines are bad in general is really an oversimplification. Especially as it points (as some have pointed out) to the usual lack of having read the documentation and learned the technology, as pixel exact rendering was reintroduced some time ago.

What you run into is the main problem that WPF is device independent and allows arbitrary zooming - so everything happens in it's own coordinate system. Which may not run down to exact a pixel. As I said - generally a feature.

Now there are edge cases (like the financial chart you point out nicely) and for that in .NET 3.0 (ages ago, seriously) pixel snapping was made available.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908(v=vs.85).aspx

has some explanations. It basically works by means of the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property.

As a matter of fact this is not the first time this question has arrived, as can be seen at - [Rendering sharp lines in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825126/rendering-sharp-lines-in-wpf).

There are a lot of features in WPF and it is quite mandatory to read the documentation. Especially in financial applications - which are not really static, if you deal with real time data. I suggest you do so - you can gain tremendous performance benefits by for example pre-caching parts of the UI in the graphics card memory, which is a simple other trick, easy to do.