# Draw soft edge line in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, line

I'm trying to draw a line in WPF (C#). I use `Line` to do it. Picture is presented below:

[image]

As you see the line has hard edges. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<Canvas RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Unspecified" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" >

    <Line RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified" X1="10" Y1="60" X2="570" Y2="570" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="4" Width="341" Canvas.Left="203" Height="505" Canvas.Top="66" />

</Canvas>
```

Comment: How are you are drawing the line; from XAML?

Comment: Might be related to (doing the oposite) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825126/rendering-sharp-lines-in-wpf

Comment: Could you post the specific code to get this result?  By default WPF controls such as Line are all vector based, so unless you're on a device with something like a sub 100 PPI this shouldn't be happening unless something not mentioned is forcing it.

Comment: No repro http://i.stack.imgur.com/gAiS3.png and that's zoomed in using the screen magnifier, which wouldn't smooth jaggies.  I'd bet OP's vidya is a POS. WPF depends on decent graphics hardware to display properly.  I wonder what a normal form would look like on his machine?